# C# string array split invalid arguments

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split

Why does this compile without error:

```
string input = "one two one three one";
string[] numbers = { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
string[] workingSplitTest = input.Split(new string[] { "one" }, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Yet this produces an invalid arguments error ("The best overloaded method match for 'string.Split(string[], System.StringSplitOptions)' has some invalid arguments"):

```
string input = "one two one three one";
string[] numbers = { "one", "two", "three", "four" };
string[] brokenSplitTest = input.Split(numbers[0], StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Both approaches reference a string array delimiter.  Am I missing something basic here?  What changes do I need to make for the second approach to work?

Comment: Because there is no overload of String.Split that accepts as first parameter a string (numbers[0] is a string not an array)

Comment: Sorry if this is a stupid question, but why does the separator need to be an array?  If there is only one delimiter, it doesn't make sense to me why an array is needed.  My understanding is that an array is only needed if I'm planning to pass >1 delimiter.  Is my thinking wrong?

Comment: You are right, there should be an overload that accepts a single `string`, but the fact is there isn't, so you can't do it. Don't look for a reason as to why this is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you index into the array `numbers[0]` the result is a single string -"one".
One option - if you need the numbers array as is - is to write it like so:

`string[] brokenSplitTest = input.Split(new string[] { numbers[0] }, StringSplitOptions.None);`

Otherwise just go with the first option.

Answer (score 0):

In the first example you pass a `string array` with the element `one`.

In the second example you pass the string literal `one` as an argument.

The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1bwe3zdy(v=vs.110).aspx) states that it expects a string array, not a literal.

Answer (score 0):

`new string[] { "one" }` is not interchangable with `numbers[0]`

The correct way to use the indexed array value here is:

`new string[] { numbers[0] }`